# Best ways to show tooltips in form fields on desktop and mobile devices

Tags: forms, gui-design, mobile, validation, tooltips

I believe this question is quite similar to [What are the best practices for tooltips on mobile websites?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35738/what-are-the-best-practices-for-tooltips-on-mobile-websites?newreg=8213190dc2f54f8bb40f7835dad27d5b), but this question is more specific (only focus on form fields) and to go deeper in how to show the same information in desktop and mobile version.

I'm thinking of a solution similar to [this jQuery example](http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/tooltip/form.html):
[image]

But this solution doesn't fit into mobile devices. And probably this is not a good solution for desktop version.

So my first question is: Is this a good way to show extra information on form fields?

If so, what is the best way to make it compatible with mobile devices?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use tool tips instead. whenever user focuses on any input show tool tip. position tool tip be below form input avoid the current position hence it will look ok in mobile also.

Comment: Thank you @prazor9 for your response. Do yo think the best position is below inputs? Thinking in mobile devices, I do not know if this position on this devices could hide and could be a little annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a good answer to this is on this article https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/ and using this solution:

[image]

Basically you add an hint directly below the label, where clear indication is given to the user and no additional scripting is added.

Comment: Thank you very much @joao-carvalho for your response. I think is the best  cross-compatible solution and probably the cleanest.

Comment: However, imagines you need to put a tooltip, because is a must of the application, do you think is a good solution to put next to the field and to open this tooltip you press it (with the mouse pointer or touching it in a mobile device) and press it once again to close?

Comment: @MiguelÁngelGarcíaGómez when is a tooltip a "must of the application"? Can you share an example?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll try to explain myself. What I'm saying with "must of the application" is a requirement from the customer. In the question there is an edit showing this new situation.

Comment: As my reputation is not enough to put more links on the original question, I put here:

Another approach is using a tooltip nex to header of form, something similar to this:

http://i68.tinypic.com/o6i650.jpg

Comment: And a solution could be this: https://osvaldas.info/examples/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly/. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you go with tooltips then I think the behavior would be: Tooltip opens when field is tapped. Tooltip is closed if user taps outside the field/the tooltip itself or other field

Comment: Also you can check this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/58157/are-tooltips-on-mobile-a-good-user-experience

Comment: Thank you @joao-carvalho! I'm sure that this could be the best solution ;)